# Function convert Hex String to BitArray C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, hex, endianness, bitarray

I created the following function which will do as requested (convert HEX string to BitArray). I am not sure about the efficiency of the function, but my main problem now is that the **Convert.ToInt64** function is *endian specific*. When this is ported over to alternate chipsets we will get different results (or exceptions). So can anyone think of an alternate way to do this conversion???

```
public BitArray convertHexToBitArray(string hexData)
    {
        string binary_values = "";
        BitArray binary_array;

            if (hexData.Length <= "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF".Length) // Max Int64
            {
                binary_values = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(hexData, 16), 2);
                binary_array = new BitArray(binary_values.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < binary_array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (binary_values[i] == '0')
                    {
                        binary_array[i] = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        binary_array[i] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
   }
```

I removed most of the error / exception handling to keep this to size so plz forgive that.

Comment: A 'chipset' is not BigEndian, a CPU core is.  A hex string isn't BE either, the MSB is always on the left.  If such a CPU core actually exists then it will run a .NET version that has a BE version of BitConverter.  This question make little sense.

Comment: Using C# mono this solution would eventually be ported onto Linux / Unix / Solaris / Non-stop and many other platforms. Our company has had problems in the past using the Convert class... Believe it or not, this is true.

Answer (score 9):

here is a simple answer, should work with a string of any length:

```
public static BitArray ConvertHexToBitArray(string hexData)
{
    if (hexData == null)
        return null; // or do something else, throw, ...

    BitArray ba = new BitArray(4 * hexData.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < hexData.Length; i++)
    {
        byte b = byte.Parse(hexData[i].ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            ba.Set(i * 4 + j, (b & (1 << (3 - j))) != 0);
        }
    }
    return ba;
}
```

Comment: I got some help from a co-worker and we came up with a similar solution. I am not very good with bit shifting but this looks good!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var int64 = Int64.Parse(hexData, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(int64);
var bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Comment: Very helpful, would require iteration to get past the 16 bytes mark, but you win the least amount of code award :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this (consider it pseduo code), but it would be fast:

```
    public static BitArray ConvertHexToBitArray(string hex)
    {
        Guard.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(hex, "hex");
        Guard.AssertHex(hex, "hex");

        var bits = new BitArray(hex.Length * 4);

        int pos = 0;

        foreach(char c in hex)
        {
            foreach(bool flag in LookupBits(c))
            {
                bits.Set(pos, flag);
                pos++;
            }
        }

        return bits;
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<char, List<bool>> _hexVsBits = CreateHexLookupTable();

    private static Dictionary<char, List<bool>> CreateHexLookupTable()
    {
        var hexVsBits = new Dictionary<char, List<bool>>();

        hexVsBits.Add('0', CreateBitsArray(false, false, false, false));
        hexVsBits.Add('1', CreateBitsArray(false, false, false, true));
        hexVsBits.Add('2', CreateBitsArray(false, false, true, false));
        hexVsBits.Add('3', CreateBitsArray(false, false, true, true));
        hexVsBits.Add('4', CreateBitsArray(false, true, false, false));
        hexVsBits.Add('5', CreateBitsArray(false, true, false, true));
        hexVsBits.Add('6', CreateBitsArray(false, true, true, false));
        hexVsBits.Add('7', CreateBitsArray(false, true, true, true));

        // complete hex table

        return hexVsBits;
    }

    private static List<bool> CreateBitsArray(bool msb, bool msbMinusOne, bool lsbPlusOne, bool lsb)
    {
        var bits = new List<bool>(4);

        bits.Add(msb);
        bits.Add(msbMinusOne);
        bits.Add(lsbPlusOne);
        bits.Add(lsb);

        return bits;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<bool> LookupBits(char hexValue)
    {
        return _hexVsBits[hexValue];
    }
}
```

And the guards:

```
public static class Guard
{
    public static void AssertHex(string value, string parameterName)
    {
        foreach(char entry in value)
        {
            if (!Char.IsNumber(entry))
            {
                if (entry != 'a' && entry != 'A' && entry != 'b' && entry != 'B' 
                    && entry != 'c' && entry != 'C' && entry != 'd' && entry != 'D' && entry != 'e' && entry != 'E' && entry != 'f' && entry != 'F')
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid hexidecimal number", parameterName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void AssertNotNullOrEmpty(string value, string parameterName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a reference to Guard.AssertHex(), or Guard.AssertNotNullOrEmpty()

Comment: I can write them out for you (I just stubbed out the Guards to give you a quick answer)

Comment: Looks great, I ended up with another solution not posted on here, but you win the most complex solution award!