# c# hex to bit conversion

Tags: c#, hex

I'm trying to convert the hexadecimal representation of a 64-bit number (e.g., the string `"FFFFFFFFF"`) to binary representation (`"11111..."`).

I've tried

```
string result = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt64(value, 16), 2);
```

but this results in a confusing compiler error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToString(object, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c

Comment: @ZombieHunter - How is that going to help? OP is not asking about converting to decimal, but to a string representing the _binary_.

Comment: Why would using `Convert.ToInt64` not work?

Comment: 64 x F(hexadecimal) with int64 gives -1, UINT gives 18446744073709551616

Comment: @santBart: `Convert.ToString(-1L, 2)` returns `"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"`, so even if the intermediate value is wrong, the result is same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a better solution, but check if this works:

```
public static string HexToBinary(string hexValue)
{
    ulong number = UInt64.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);

    string binaryString = string.Empty;
    foreach (byte singleByte in bytes)
    {
        binaryString += Convert.ToString(singleByte, 2);
    }

    return binaryString;
}
```

The most convenient way would be to use [`Convert.ToString(Int64, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wse73s4.aspx), but there is no overload for ulong. Another solution is [`Convert.ToString(UInt64, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81x3t779.aspx) and write your own IFormatProvider. By looking at the examples I found an IFormatProvider that formats numbers in binary, octal and hex string representation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx.
The code there looks very similar to what I provided, so I thinks its not a bad solution.

Answer (score 10):

What's wrong with the following code?

```
string hex = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";

// Returns -1
long longValue = Convert.ToInt64(hex, 16);

// Returns 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
string binRepresentation = Convert.ToString(longValue, 2);
```

Pretty much what you wrote (only fixed the `ulong` to `long` cast), and returns what you expect.

Edit:
undeleted this answer, as even if the `long` representation is signed, the binary representation is actually what you expect.

Comment: OP has `Convert.ToUInt64`, not `Convert.ToInt64` (unsigned, not signed).

Comment: @ken2k - Spot on. althought the signed long int writes as -1 it's binary representation is correct.

Comment: Is there a reason that this would be considered better than the accepted answer? it appears that the accepted answer would be "safer", but this one is more voted on, so I would assume it's completely safe.

Answer (score 3):

The best choice is :

```
public static string hex2bin(string value)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(value, 16), 2).PadLeft(value.Length * 4, '0');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute approach, no pancy 64bit limit:

```
string HexStringToBinary(string hexString)
{
    var lup = new Dictionary<char, string>{
            { '0', "0000"},
            { '1', "0001"},
            { '2', "0010"}, 
            { '3', "0011"},

            { '4', "0100"}, 
            { '5', "0101"}, 
            { '6', "0110"}, 
            { '7', "0111"},

            { '8', "1000"}, 
            { '9', "1001"}, 
            { 'A', "1010"}, 
            { 'B', "1011"},

            { 'C', "1100"}, 
            { 'D', "1101"}, 
            { 'E', "1110"}, 
            { 'F', "1111"}};                

    var ret = string.Join("", from character in hexString
                              select lup[character]);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269737/function-convert-hex-string-to-bitarray-c-sharp) to convert the hex string into a BitArray then the task of producing the binary representation is trivial:

```
BitArray barray = ConvertHexToBitArray(string hexData)
var sbuild = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < barray.Length; i++)
{
    sbuild.Append(barray[i] ? "1" : "0");
}
Console.WriteLine(sbuild.ToString());
```