# C# How to Convert a hexadecimal string into an array of bits

Tags: c#, string, binary, hex, byte

I have this hexadecimal string hexavalue="03" where each digit represent 4 bit such that in the end both values will give me a bit array of 8 bit.

But i don't know how to convert that value into a bit array in c# .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function convert Hex String to BitArray C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269737/function-convert-hex-string-to-bitarray-c-sharp)

Comment: Try following linq :             string input = "01020304050607080910";
           //get nibbles iin groups of two
            byte[] bytes = input.Select((x, i) => new { nibble = x, index = i }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 2).Select(x => byte.Parse(x.First().nibble.ToString() + x.Last().nibble.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();